# To check if ServiceWorker is in waiting state

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, wait

I am trying to understand the Service Worker API, and I know the bits and parts about registering a Service Worker.

As stated in the API doc, if a service worker update is found, the service worker is registered and added to the queue. This SW takes over a page if and only if, the page is closed and opened again.That is, A window is closed and reopened again.

Now, this has a few downfalls:

1. The user might be seeing a previous version that might have a very serious grammatical mistake, or whatever.
2. The user needs to be somehow notified that the content has changed and that a referesh would do it.

I know how to tell the `SW.js` to `skipWaiting()` and take over. I also know how to send a message to the `SW.js` telling it that the user wants a automatic refresh.

However, what I do not know is how to know whether a new SW is actually in a waiting state.

I have used this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((a) => {
        console.log("Response, ", a);
        if (a.waiting !== null && a.waiting.state === "installed") {
            console.log("okay");
        }

    });
```

However, it usually returns the waiting state as `null`.(Possibly because the SW is still installing when the request is fired.)

How can I know on the client page that a waiting service worker is available?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's some code that will detect and allow you to handle various states whenever there's a new or updated service worker registration.

Please note that the log message assumes that `skipWaiting()` is not being called during the service worker's installation; if it is being called, then instead of having to close all tabs to get the new service worker to activate, it will just activate automatically.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', async function() {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
    if (registration.waiting && registration.active) {
      // The page has been loaded when there's already a waiting and active SW.
      // This would happen if skipWaiting() isn't being called, and there are
      // still old tabs open.
      console.log('Please close all tabs to get updates.');
    } else {
      // updatefound is also fired for the very first install. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
      registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
        registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
          if (event.target.state === 'installed') {
            if (registration.active) {
              // If there's already an active SW, and skipWaiting() is not
              // called in the SW, then the user needs to close all their
              // tabs before they'll get updates.
              console.log('Please close all tabs to get updates.');
            } else {
              // Otherwise, this newly installed SW will soon become the
              // active SW. Rather than explicitly wait for that to happen,
              // just show the initial "content is cached" message.
              console.log('Content is cached for the first time!');
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I should have checked the docs myself, though. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Jeff, it seems, I've found an error in your code: 'waiting' is not a valid state of service worker ('installing', 'installed', 'activating', 'activated' and 'redundant' are valid states of service worker). 'waiting' (along with 'installing' and 'active') is the attribute of the registration, not the service worker.

Comment: Thanks; I've been using https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/f3e173a89adfd0ce1e664442ae7f8a27 more recently, and will update my old answer.

Comment: @JeffPosnick just checking where `updatedSW` is defined?

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from an earlier version. I've switched it to use `event.target` instead.